# Drawing with Drawrect

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics

dear objectiveC masters,
I'm a newbie apple programmer and since I'm currently taking a master degree in math education, I want the make a thesis on making apps that based on math education..

Right now, I'm trying to make an iPad app that draws a sine function and then transforms the sine function. I draw the sine graph by overriding the drawrect function in a custom uiview class and load it to a uiview object. The sine function is drawn nicely on a context, along with grids and axes that are drawn on different contexts.

I put several sliders and then plan to use the sliders to change the variables in the uiview class that i use for drawing. Now here's the problem, I realize that I can't access the variables in the viewcontroller from the custom uiview class, and I suspect that I may have mistakenly used the wrong paradigm in writing the whole program.

Can someone help me to clear the confusion here? It doesn't have to be in the exact codes but more to the big pictures of how I should draw and redraw the sine function on a view object whilst changing the variables of the sine function through sliders.

Thank you for your kind help :) 
Chandra from Indonesia.

Comment: Hello Pii, are there still some open questions?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Instead of letting the UIView ask the values from the UIViewController, you can also push the values to the UIVIew the moment one of the sliders changes. This way the UIView does what it should do: draw what the ViewController asks him to.
   Think of a function like `redrawUsingNewValues:` that you implement in the UIView and you call from the UIViewController.
2. Use delegation. If you really want the UIView to be in control, you can give it a pointer to the UIViewController using delegation. That way the UIView doesn't own the UIViewController, but you can get the values you want.
   An introduction on delegation can be found here: [Delegation and the Cocoa Frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html)

Good luck on your program!

Comment: Jacco.. Thank you for your answer.. I haven't been using delegation other than for releasing the keyboard, LoL.. I guess I need to step aside for a while to study more on the delegation-thingy then.. Is this the "right" way or would it be easier if I just postpone to explore the delegation-thingy and just push that value like what you said in #1?

Comment: iOS is highly MVC (Model-View-Controller) based.
In this case that means that you want the viewCONTROLLER to be in control of the view (what's in a name ;)) I would recommend keeping the view as stupid as possible (only display stuff) and keep the ViewController in control of everything else. That means that option #1 is the way to go.
1. create the variables you need on your UIView as public properties
2. fill in your drawrect function to use these variables
3. when a slider changes, change the variables of your UIView in the ViewController
4. call [yourView drawrect] to redraw

Comment: That's is absolutely right! It is still hard for me to apply the MVC model, because I just want to do everything without even thinking what is the role of every class.. Your wisdom gives me insight! LOL... Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

1. A method in the UIViewController should recognize when the slider values changes
2. the same method should trigger another methode within the UIViewController to update/recalculate the sine function values (e.g. creating an value array)
3. at the end of the update-methode the necessary values are transferred to the UIView via an outlet from UIViewController to the UIView (the UIView is an property of the UIViewController)
4. the UIView is drawing the new sine-function in draw rect

Edit 1:
your ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class YourGraphUIView; // that's you view where you draw

@interface ResultViewController: UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *valueFromSlider; //bound to your UISlider
@property (weak) IBOutlet YourGraphUIView *yourGraphUIView; //bound to your costumUIView
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *graphValue;

- (IBAction)takeSliderValue:(id)sender; //bound to your UISlider

@end
```

your ViewController.m:

```
#import "ResultViewController.h"
#import "YourGraphUIView.h"

@interface ResultViewController ()

@end

@implementation ResultViewController
@synthesize yourGraphUIView, valueFromSlider, graphValue;

- (IBAction)takeSliderValue:(UISlider *)sender{

graphValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[(double)sender.value]]; //takes value from UISlider
yourGraphUIView.graphValue = graphValue; //gives the value to the yourGraphUIView
[self.yourGraphUIView setNeedsDisplay] //<--- important to redraw UIView after changes
}
end
```

your YourGraphUIView.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface YourGraphUIView : UIView

@property(nonatomic, retain)NSNumber *graphValue;

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)dirtyRect;

@end
```

your YourGraphUIView.m:

```
#import "YourGraphUIView.h"

@implementation YoutGraphUIView

@synthesize graphValue;

//... init, draw rect with using the graphValue for calculating and updating the graph

end;
```

I hope this helped. You should have a look how to build the GUI and how to connect the UIViews. You need to set the custom classes for the ViewController and the YourGraphUIView as well. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, JFS! I'm not sure if I grabbed your idea..  It's just that I'm still very new at this Xcode thing, and I don't have yet the clear big picture of how should I really work.. I don't want to develop a bad habit of making patches to cover the holes in my program.. So many tutorials and books to study, but I can't wait to finish all of those materials first.. I hope you understand what I meant..

Comment: Wow! Thanks for writing it down for me.. I get your idea of passing the property.. I've tried it, and I got an error message said that Xcode couldn't find the property on that object even though I had imported the UI custom class and synthesized the property.. Any idea what went wrong? Another question is about the NSNumber object that you created, does it have to be an object so that it can have the retain on its property to be passed along classes? I tried to pass CGpoint property but I couldn't, I thought it was because it wasn't an object? Forgive my cluttered mind, hehe..

Comment: It's hard to tell where the issue is without the code. Did you bind the UIView to the ViewController and did you set the custom class to UIView and to UIViewController? The value doesn't have to be an object it can be a primitive as well. But be aware that `CGPoint` is not just an var `The data structure CGPoint represents a point in a two-dimensional coordinate system.`

Comment: Yes, all the connection seems okay, and thanks for reminding about the CGPoint.. Great, I'll try to figure out what went wrong then.. Thanks so much Buddy :)

Comment: I missed one important portion. In order to update the view you need to set the following in the `takeSliderValue` method: `[self.yourGraphUIView setNeedsDisplay]`.

Comment: It is actually cleaner to put the `setNeedsDisplay` call inside the `setGraphValue:` setter of the view, instead of having the controller call it.

Comment: In `YourGraphUIView`'s implementation: `- (void)setGraphValue:(NSNumber *)graphValue { _graphValue = graphValue; [self setNeedsDisplay]; }` (assuming you use ARC and the modern auto synthesis of properties in Xcode... otherwise, add the necessary retain/release calls and set the correct instance variable). That way the display always matches the value of the property of the view.

Comment: Also, why the boxing/unboxing of the value in a `NSNumber`? You can use a `float` or any other scalar value directly...

Comment: @Guillaume, you are right. Using float or double would be more straight forward.